# Behaviour of set-intersection of objects

Tags: python, class, set

I stumbled upon this uncertainty in one of my programs:
Suppose we have a Class deriving from int with a custom attribute.

```py
class A(int):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, value)

    def __init__(self, _, a):
        self.a = a
```

Objects of this class are now used in a Set.

```py
set1 = {A(2, 5), A(3, 2)}
set2 = {A(3, 7), A(5, 5)}
```

How would I now know the output of the following operations?

```py
x, = set1 & set2
print(x.a)

x, = set2 & set1
print(x.a)

x, = set1.intersection(set2)
print(x.a)
...
```

It appeared to me in various tests that the result is rather random, could somebody explain this behaviour?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What exactly struggles you? Why changing the order changes the result? Or why it prints what it prints?

Comment: I discovered inconsistencies in the result, with sometimes having the same object on `a & b` as well as `b & a` returned. I guess I'd like to know how intersection works!

Comment: oh, so you say that the result is non deterministic? Are you sure? If so, it struggles me too :o

Comment: I'd say so, yes! Could be a bug on my side, but fairly confident it is.

Comment: You inherited from `int` without overloading the `__hash__` or `__eq__` methods. Which means you're saying all `A`s with the same *first* argument are equivalent, regardless of what the other arguments might be. It doesn't matter which object survives; you said they were all equivalent, so which object is picked as the survivor is an irrelevant implementation detail. If you cared, you'd define hashing and equality properly.

Comment: Also, `return super(cls, cls).__new__(cls, value)` is *wrong* (terrible things will happen if you inherit from this class). Just use `return super().__new__(cls, value)` and let Python do the right thing for you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Follow-up-question. Is it possible to define the survivor? `__eq__` only seems to affect set-intersection in a sense that they are tested for equality.

Comment: @Raumschifffan: No, it's not, it will *always* be implementation-dependent. You said the two were equivalent, so Python assumes it doesn't matter which one wins. That's on you. You can do dumb stuff with a `dict` that performs a self-mapping (key and value are the same), so you can extract what is mapped to and choose whether or not to replace it, but it's a terrible brittle idea. If the rest of the value matters, make it part of the equality check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You intrigued me so much that I looked into [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b878f206b71f/Objects/setobject.c#l1242) and it became quite logical. We looped over [smaller set](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b878f206b71f/Objects/setobject.c#l1258) and search every element in bigger one. When both sets has equal size, the order matters (that's why you get different results in your case), otherwise the elements taken will always belong to smaller set.